# Why a monoid has only one object but many arrows different from identity?

Tags: category-theory, monoid

In Category Theory, a monoid is defined as "a category with one object [...] thus determined by the set of all its arrows, by the identity arrow and by the rule for the composition of arrows"[1].

If there is only one single object, then the domain and codomain assigns, to every arrow, the same object, a. Thus, every arrow has as domain the same object as codomain.

Given the definition of category, the identity operation assigns an arrow with dom f = cod f = a.

- Why can I say that the monoid has many arrows?? Why the different arrows are not the id?
- If I buy they are different arrows, then which axiom of the category definition asserts that the identity is the one that maps each element (inside the set) to itself? I thought the arrows were supposed 'not to see' the interns of the objects.
- What is the nature of the domain/codomain then? How f and g are diferent if the objects they point from/to are the same?

[1] Mac Lane, Category theory for the working mathematician, p.11

Comment: The last sentence of that paragraph on p.11 might help: For an object $a$ of a category, the arrows in $hom(a,a)$ can be composed with each other because domain and codomain match up. The category axioms guarantee that

(1) The composition is associative.

(2) $id_a$ is a unit for this composition.

This means that $hom(a,a)$ is a monoid. In general there can be many arrows in $hom(a,a)$ beside $id_A$.

Conversely, if you have a monoid M, you can take a category with one object $a$ and define $hom(a,a)=M$ with composition the monoid multiplication.